# Alternative for the phrase "in a word"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have the following sentence:

> So, in a word, my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken.

I have read elsewhere that using the phrase "in a word" here is not best practice - because I have an entire clause after it.

What would be an alternative way to say what I'm trying to get across? I am trying to say that if I had to write it down or describe it, then this is my goal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the preceding sentence/context? You could possibly introduce the clause with `i.e.`

Comment: In a word is fine for spoken English.

Comment: Briefly, use: *briefly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an idiomatic expression you may use:

***[In a nutshell:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-a-nutshell)***

> You can use in a nutshell to indicate that you are saying something in a very brief way, using few words.
>
> - In a nutshell, the owners thought they knew best.
>   This, in a nutshell, is what Richard Chaplin appears to have done.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 4):

You could use "[*in short*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-short)"

> So, in short, my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken.

Do not, however, take the meaning of "*in a word*" literally. Your example is fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> So, basically, my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken

From Dictionary.com 
[basically](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/basically?s=t)

> 2. (sentence modifier) in essence; in summary; put simply basically we had underestimated mother nature

There are also a couple of words in the [thesauraus entry](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/basically?s=t) from dictionary.com that would fit.

> So essentially my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken
>
> So in essence my goal ist to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken

Answer (score 0):

[*Succinctly*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/succinct) - meaning briefly or in short.

To put it succinctly; my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken

Alternatives:

- In brief
- The long and short of it
- To cut a long story short
- In summary

Bonus: *TL:DR* - pronounced "Tee-el-Dee-are", acronym for "Too long - didn't read". It's internet slang, but depending on your audience and purpose of writing would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: 'Succinctly' is a perfectly good word, but it somehow looks out of place in a sentence about KFC...

Comment: You've got a point - it is out of place against the rest of the sentence - part of the reason I added the alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Suffice it to say,
my goal is to eat Kentucky Fried Chicken.

Comment: This would be improved with some explanation of why this is superior to the original.

Comment: You'll notice that all the other answers (so far) include not just an explanation but also a link to a dictionary definition. You can [edit] your answer to provide a similar level of detail. You may be unaware that EL&U isn't a forum to post personal suggestions; we're looking for *authoritative answers supported by evidence*. For further guidance, see [answer], and take our site's **[Tour]**. :-)